# React Router Dynamic Route: Invalid URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, dynamic-routing

### 1) In React Router

`<Route path={"/movie/:id"} component={ResultPage} />`

### 2) Search Component

#### When I search for movies it hits the API and displays a `Result` component.Each result `Link`s to a dynamic route (above).

```js
<div className="results">
  {data.map((movie) => (
    <Result
      poster_path={movie.poster_path}
      alt={movie.title}
      key={movie.id}
      id={movie.id}
      title={movie.title}
      overview={movie.overview}
      release_date={movie.release_date}
      genre_ids={movie.genre_ids}
    />
  ))}
</div>;
```

[image]

### 3) Result Component

#### I pass some props in the `Link` and use `props.location.state` to fetch the rest of the movie's data for this `ResultPage` component.

```js
export default function Result(props) {
  const { poster_path: poster, alt, title } = props;

  return (
    <div className="result">
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: `/movie/${title}`,
          state: { ...props },
        }}
      >
        <img
          src={
            poster
              ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${poster}`
              : "https://www.genius100visions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/placeholder-vertical.jpg"
          }
          alt={alt}
        />
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### 4) ResultPage component

#### You can see the URL is now `http://disnyplus.plus/movie/avengers-endgame` however if you open a new tab and copy/paste the same URL the page will error because it doesn't have all the data is my guess, since it got it from the `props` from the Search -> Click Result -> ResultPage flow.

#### Is there another approach to achieve this or is a side-effect of using dynamic pages and passing `props` to it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the data that are stored in the props.location.state are not accessible when users refresh the page or visit the page without redirecting from the search page. As a result, it would not be a good practice.

I would recommend keeping the title ( or id ) of the movie in the URL ( as you have already done), and then receive the desired data in the `ResultPage component` based on the title or id of the movie. You can take advantage of React lifecycles to send a request in order to fetch the data. You can read more about the best way of fetching data in class and functional components [here in the documnetation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html).

The other solution that can solve your issue, but I would not recommend, is storing the data in Cookies or Local Storage and make them accessible on reloads.

Comment: Thanks, let me re-explain to make sure I understand. 1) Don't pass `...props` via Link. 2) Fetch everything on `ResultPage` component so it can "stand alone" if we just type in the specific URL. But I would still need to pass the `id` via the `Link` because the API endpoint uses an `id` to fetch all that data `(https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=${API_KEY}&append_to_response=videos,images,release_dates,credits)`. So i don't know what to do about that?

Comment: Yes, you got it completely right. In that case, replace the `title` in the URL with the `id`  of movies. So, they can be used to send the appropriate data of each movie in the result component

Comment: Sounds good, so there's no way to pass the `id` in the URL but display the name in the URL, `http://disnyplus.plus/movie/space-jam-a-new-legacy` vs `http://disnyplus.plus/movie/379686`. Like to _prettify_ a URL. I don't mind this id URL approach but obviously the names look better

Comment: It would not be possible because in addition to the refresh, the user might visit the movie page as the first page without any history. So you would have to include id in the URL, or change the API and send a request by name, not by id, or include both or name and id in the URL.

Comment: Pls also mark this answer as the correct answer if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the problem with client-side routing, basically before you can hit your url, in this case `http://disnyplus.plus/movie/avengers-endgame`, your browser makes a request to the server and since there is no server-routing present, the page will result in an error. It does so because not all javascript necessary to get the movie has been performed. React let's you open pages on your website without refreshing by performing some javascript.

One of the possible solutions I could recommend is using HashRouter instead, your urls would look something like this `http://disnyplus.plus/#/movie/avengers-endgame`.

Hash routes ignore the part of the url after the hash so they don't ask server for the specific url, but what they do is call the index page first and then render what they are supposed to accordingly.

If you are curious, I think this answer really nailed the server/client/hybrid side routing even though the question doesn't match yours. I think you could learn something from it.

[React-router urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm going to read this over!